# PFObject or PFFile for storing sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

If I'm planning on storing sound data of about 8 seconds long, does it makes sense to store it using `PFObject` or `PFFile`? Also, how would I establish a `one-to-many relationship` between this sound object (or file) and several users? Are `Pointers` the best method?

Answer (score 0):

Use PFFile.
There are several ways to establish a one-to-many relationship. For more details, you can check the options at [enter link description here](https://www.parse.com/docs/relations_guide)

Personally, I think you can just add a field named, say soundFile, in the _User class of your app's dashboard on parse. The type should be PFFile. Then save the sound PFFile in that field. Something like the following:

```
NSData *yourSoundData; 
 PFFile *soundFile = [PFFile fileWithData:yourSoundData];
 [soundFile save];
 for (PFUser *user in userLists) {
    user[@"soundFile"] = soundFile;
}
```

Be noted that save function will block your main thread, you may need to change it according to your needs by using its variants, such as saveInbackground.